# How do I Connect EC2 instance to Android App?

Tags: python, android, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm developing an Android App and I want the users to upload some images to an EC2 instance in order to process them using some fancy python code, and then return the final images to the user. I am new with servers and AWS, it's a little bit confusing, there are too much things that seem related, but I am not sure where to look. What can I do to achieve my goal? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Long story short, I am gonna put things into the list in sequential order to make things easier for you.

1. Spin off an EC2 instance (Instance class as per your CPU/Network/Memory Requirements).
2. Install required dependencies and Publish code into your EC2 Instance (Via GitHub or CI/CD. Github will be a straightforward way for you as a beginner.)
3. Run your code.
4. Configure security groups which will allow the internet to communicate with your instance. Security groups help you define which port to open to the internet and make it accessible from your android app.
5. Connect your code via EC2 IP or public IP domain exposed by every EC2 instance (If configured with the public IP option).

These are the basic things you need to do for a simple DIY set-up as a beginner. This will be a good start but definitely not recommended for production usage. For production usage, you need to familiarise yourself with the concept of VPCs, Subnets, NATs, IGWs, Security Groups, Load Balancers, AutoScaling Groups, ACM for SSL certificate management and Cloudwatch for alerting and logging.

I hope this will help you to kickstart.

> Note: If you are a beginner and this is just a hobby learning project then I would recommend not to get into advanced concepts like VPCs, subnets etc. and start with humble beginnings. Once you achieve that, look into more security + availability of your existing setup. Do things in smaller increments rather than everything all at once. Happy Coding.

Comment: Thank you, bro. Is there an easier way for production, or who could I hire to do it?